# Why do some of blips have superscript letters or question marks?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTAV, some blips on the map have some superscript letters or symbols. Generally, the superscript is a question mark, but sometimes it is another letter. How do these blips differ from the others?

[image: Map, showing two symbols with question marks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are Missions that are not part of the Main Storyline, the question mark is asking if you would like to partake in them as they are optional

Source: https://gtaforums.com/topic/644250-which-symbols-are-the-main-missions/

Comment: Welcome to the site, do you have sources to support your answer? Links to official sites with the information will greatly improve your answer.

Comment: why have I been banned?

Comment: Likely due to the large number of low quality posts you have made, been downvoted, and subsequently deleted.  It's an automated restriction, based on how your posts were received.

Comment: @NickSings Thanks for coming back and editing your answer, it is much better now that you have included a source. Now that your answer is getting some upvotes you should you have some more privileges (you can even up-vote Questions and answers now)